# CSS - Vertical oriented tabs

Tags: css, tabs, vertical-alignment

Good evening!
At the moment I have a horizontal oriented tabs. In addition I would like some vertical oriented tabs on right side of the same tab content.

I am able to turn the < li > orientation, but not able to align the new tabs on to of each other on the right side of the tab content.

This is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
      <ul class="tab-links">
          <li class="active"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Video">Video</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Media">Media</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li id="rotate"><a href="#CV">CV</a></li>
          <li id="rotate"><a href="#Pro">Prosjekter</a></li>
      </ul> 
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="About" class="tab active">
            <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Video" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Media" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Contact" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="CV" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #5 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

         <div id="Pro" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #6 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>          



    </div> <!-- End content-body -->
```

CSS:

```
/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width:475px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float:right;

}

/*----- Tab Links -----*/
/* Clearfix */
.tab-links:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
}

.tab-links li {
    margin:-5px 7px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;

}

    .tab-links a {
        padding:9px 15px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        background:#df8b67;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        /*font-family: MoviePoster;*/
    }

    .tab-links a:hover {
        background:#d25a26;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#d25a26;
    color:#fff;
}

    /*----- Tab right -----*/
/* Clearfix */
.tab-link-right:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
}



.tab-links-right li {
    margin:-5px 7px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline;
}

    .tab-links-right a {
        padding:9px 15px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        background:#df8b67;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  
        /*font-family: MoviePoster;*/
    }

    .tab-links-right a:hover {
        background:#d25a26;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#d25a26;
    color:#fff;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
.tab-content {
    margin-top: -14px;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d25a26;
    height:447px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2.5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2.5px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2.5px #888;
}

    .tab {
        display:none;
    }

    .tab.active {
        display:block;
    }

#rotate {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4L08bd76/)?

Comment: Well no! The CV and Prosjekter tabs should be placed along the right hand side of the tab content box.

Comment: or like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/4L08bd76/3/

Comment: @Sepi: Answer is updated as per your requirement. Please view and mark it as answer if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated after OP's comment**

First of all you're missing a closing tag of your `tabs div`. Secondly you can't assign same id `rotate` for two elements. I gave separate `Ids` to the rotating elements and them gave them the following `CSS` replacing your `rotate` class. and **didn't change any thing else in the CSS**

Assigned `Ids` like this:

```
<li id="verOne"><a href="#CV">CV</a></li>
<li id="verTwo"><a href="#Pro">Prosjekter</a></li>
```

and the **CSS:**

```
li#verTwo {
position: absolute;
left: 450px;
top: 80px;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

li#verOne {
position: absolute;
left: 478px;
top: 185px;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

*Below is the working demo with complete code.*

```css
/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width:475px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float:right;

}

/*----- Tab Links -----*/
/* Clearfix */
.tab-links:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
}

.tab-links li {
    margin:-5px 7px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;

}

    .tab-links a {
        padding:9px 15px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        background:#df8b67;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        /*font-family: MoviePoster;*/
    }

    .tab-links a:hover {
        background:#d25a26;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#d25a26;
    color:#fff;
}

    /*----- Tab right -----*/
/* Clearfix */
.tab-link-right:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
}



.tab-links-right li {
    margin:-5px 7px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline;
}

    .tab-links-right a {
        padding:9px 15px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        background:#df8b67;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  
        /*font-family: MoviePoster;*/
    }

    .tab-links-right a:hover {
        background:#d25a26;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#d25a26;
    color:#fff;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
.tab-content {
    margin-top: -14px;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d25a26;
    height:447px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2.5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2.5px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2.5px #888;
}

    .tab {
        display:none;
    }

    .tab.active {
        display:block;
    }

li#verTwo {
position: absolute;
left: 450px;
top: 80px;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

li#verOne {
position: absolute;
left: 478px;
top: 185px;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
      <ul class="tab-links">
          <li class="active"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Video">Video</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Media">Media</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li id="verOne"><a href="#CV">CV</a></li>
          <li id="verTwo"><a href="#Pro">Prosjekter</a></li>
      </ul> 
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="About" class="tab active">
            <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Video" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Media" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Contact" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="CV" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #5 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

         <div id="Pro" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #6 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>          



    </div> <!-- End content-body -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually I was thinking something like this:
http://pastebin.com/2KfDhx0N
Sorry if I was confusing you!

Comment: @Sepi: no need to say sorry. I updated the code and its working you can view it. and please mark it answer if this is what you need.